# Is it advisable to use multiple ReadyBoost flash drives?

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, readyboost

I am a fan of ReadyBoost and have seen good results using it with my work laptop. I tried something today and connected a second flash drive (2GB) and configured it for use with ReadyBoost. The first is an 8GB configured with 4GB for ReadyBoost. I'm using Windows 7 RC 7100 and was wondering if using more than one ReadyBoost drive helps?

Comment: I suspect the answer is yes, but your question is very confusing – perhaps you’d like to re-order it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft only recommends using "[one to three times the amount of RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost)" in your computer. Anything over that won't give you a measurable performance boost.

That aside, multiple Readyboost drives is a new trick in Windows 7. Measure your potential gain (baring in mind the 3x Ram rule) versus the added complexity and potential for failure of using a new tool.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine it would hurt. More space = more caching for your programs.